# On 'how much money do I need for [x] days in [y]' questions

Tags: discussion, scope

We seem to get a lot of questions about how much money one needs for a holiday in a given place, these are invariably closed (correctly, imo) as opinion based.

What about a question like "What resources are there for working out how much money I need for a holiday?" where the question specifically didn't mention places or duration. I think that's on-topic but may be too broad ...

I was thinking someone (i.e. me) could ask/answer it (maybe as a community-wiki) and then direct any of the country specific questions to that answer.

Answer (score 4):

As you say yourself, a "What resources are there for working out how much money I need for a holiday?" question will be closed as too broad, and with good reason. However, if you think you can provide a reasonably comprehensive answer to the question yourself as a community wiki, then this can be allowed. [We already have a precedent](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1697/793) on a somewhat related topic, and it had a moderate success (not that many views, but good amount of rep, showing the community generally supports such posts).

Take some inspiration from the post and see my answer to the meta question for some guidelines/remarks.

Feel free to link back to the CW question in your own post when you write it for easy reference.

Comment: OK, it might take me a while to pull together enough for a good starting point but I'll see what I can do and then edit this question.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out [we have quite a few such questions (of which this link is just an example)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=how%20much%20money%20[money]), and with good reason too: it's understandable how the issue at hand relates to budgeting travels. I understand our policy of closing as `primarily opinion based` all questions who read remotely like `how much money do I need in X?`. Nevertheless I still feel that this *is* a travel-related query and we, on TSE, should be able to deal with it in an efficient fashion.

I therefore agree with the proposal of a canonical answer to the question `What resources are there for working out how much money I need for a holiday?` How about providing an answer based on sensible economical metrics  and authoritative sources? Off the top of my head I would say [ppp metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchasing_power_parity#Measurement) such as the [Big Mac index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Mac_Index) and a calculation example could be included in such a canonical answer.

Comment: Most of those in the search are NOT 'how much do I need for x days' but how much you need for visas etc, or are closed.  Policy should stay for the subjective ones, but agree on a canonical 'resources for calculating' question.

Comment: [Eg Trekhard](http://trekhard.com/calculator#eat=18&sleep=25&trek=25&trekfreq=5&balance=13)